# JQuery - Window resized from DOM - fire event

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a browser window is resized, I understand there's a JQuery method to hook it up to a event handler.

I was wondering if there's one, if the window is resized from the DOM, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

```
$(window).bind('resize', function() {
    alert('Resizing now');
});
```

Comment: It works even when the user is not manually resizing the window but its done automatically from say a function?