# Call a function when window is resized under 480px

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way in JavaScript or jQuery to call a function when the window is resized under 480px?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662726/jquery-window-resized-from-dom-fire-event?rq=1 Use window.outerWidth or window.innerWidth to get dimensions

Comment: @DmitryPashkevich That question is asking something completely different to this one.

Comment: Essentially the questions (and answers) are the same. Here's another *extremely similar* thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996431/javascript-detect-when-a-window-is-resized?rq=1 Personally, I get pissed when I search for something on SO and get a bunch of nearly identical threads...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With jQuery you can do it as follows:

```
$(window).on("resize", function() {
    if ($(this).width() < 480) {     // or $(this).height() for height check
        // function();
    }
});
```

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).on("resize", function() {
    if ($(this).width() < 480) {
        alert('your width is under 480')
    }
});



</script>

Comment: @Alex It will work when you start to resize the window. If you do not change the window size the alert won't display.

Comment: it doesn't work when you resize it do you want me to give you a live link?

Comment: @alex Also after alert i believe you are missing a ;

Comment: hi there, it works fine in Chrome but in FF the screen goes black freezing completely, really strange :O

Comment: Yes i can confirm that. Try putting $(document).ready(function() {}); around your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use resize event on Window (http://api.jquery.com/resize/), then check the size of the window, and if its under 480px, call your method.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ask for

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        var counter=1;
        $(window).resize(function()
        {
            alert($(this).width());
            if ($(this).width() < 1000)
            {
                counter = incCounter(counter);
            }
            alert("counter = " + counter);
        });
        function incCounter(intvari)
        {
            backValue = intvari;
            backValue++;
            return backValue;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Text
</body>
</html>
```

?

Comment: the function needs to be called as soon as the window is resized under 480px. Thanks

Comment: basically I have a jQuery accordion and I want to make it work only for smartphones, so I was thinking of writing a function that would call the jQuery accordion only under a certain width.

Comment: I updated my answer. Honestly your question is a little bit too vargue.

Answer (score 0):

```
var w=$(window).width();
if(w<480)
{
alert(w);
}
```